# App rejected due to "missing restore mechanism"

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My application was rejected due to "missing restore mechanism". I don't understand because I put the restore button in a `UIAlertView`.

[image: restore alert view]

Comment: It's not enough of you put it in an alert. It must be visible and tappable directly from within the app. If you have a "buy" button and then you show that alert you attached, then it will be rejected. Buy and restore should be separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the functionality that Apple is asking you to put into your app is to provide a "restore" ability.

[If one deletes your app (which they paid for) and wants to restore it later, they've still paid for it.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204530)  And that's the functionality you need to make happen.

[Here is a tutorial that talks about what to do](http://gregheo.com/blog/iap-restore/), in terms of code.

Answer (score 1):

You must add Restore button whenever you used in App purchase in your app.

as per apple documentation there is several types of in app purchases. one of them is "non-consumable n app purchase". Nonconsumable inapp purchase means the user have to paid for that only once, he do not need to paid for the same item again.

But now question is that if user deletes your app from device then how can he get his/her product back without any type of payment. for this purpose apple recommends to the developer to add the RESTORE button in app when there is in app purchase.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

The above link is for in app purchase where you can find extra information about restore and some helpful code.

Hope this help someone.